# Best way to integrate legacy phpBB forum into Joomla

Tags: joomla

What is the best way to integrate a legacy phpBB forum into a new Joomla site?

Basically I want to keep the navigation links (top and main menu), and embed the forum as pages in the site.

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need user integration for Joomla and phpBB you can use [JFusion](http://www.jfusion.org/), so people logged in Joomla will be logged in phpBB. Registered users in Joomla will be replicated to phpBB too (and vice versa, you have to setup JFusion configuration to decide which system is the "master"). I've been using JFusion with a Moodle and Joomla installation and it's working pretty well.

To "integrate" your forum to your Joomla installation, you have a fast implementation: in your top menu, create a link and change it's `Menu Item Type` to `Wrapper`. In `Parameters`, set `Wrapper URL` to your phpBB path. This way you will have an iframe with your forum.

If you need a more robust solution, I would try to develop a component.

Comment: I was just about to add an answer with the Wrapper solution myself. It is great and just what we need. The "auto height" option is magnificent, giving us a built-in solution for adjusting the iframe height dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I would theme the forum appropriately and put it on a sub-domain like `http://forum.mydomain.com`. This way it's unlikely to clash with the rest of your website.

Comment: I don't want to clash it. I want to *integrate* it.

Comment: Then you need to better define what you mean by "integrate". From your question I get the impression that with "integrate" you mean from a visitors/users point of view. If this is the case then my answer would  probably the best way to go since you're keeping two completely different systems separated but seemingly "integrated" at the same time.